# MySQLi start result order by selection and continue to next results

Tags: php, mysqli

So this is really starting to bug me... I am displaying images in a gallery, shown at first by thumbnails. You can click the first thumbnail and it will load the images in order by filename `ASC`, this is great for starting from the beginning.

However, when you click a random image, it will load that image, when you click next, it brings the whole album right back to the beginning again, which isn't so great. I am trying to sort it out so that you can click a random image, and once you click next, the actual next result is shown instead of taking you back to the start?

Here is my current code, you can see the differences from non-selecting and selecting a choice:

```
  if($select_first == ''){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `new_images` WHERE `alb_ref` = '$alb_ref' ORDER BY full_link ASC";      
  } else {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `new_images` WHERE `alb_ref` = '$alb_ref' ORDER BY full_link = '$select_first' DESC, full_link ASC";
  }
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
          if ($result->num_rows > 0) {    

$i = 0;
              while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              $image_id = $row['img_id'];
              $thumb_link = $row['thumb_link'];
```

It's that one line of code which needs changing but I'm not so good with MySQLi queries to know how to fix this? Any ideas?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `new_images` WHERE `alb_ref` = '$alb_ref' ORDER BY full_link = '$select_first' DESC, full_link ASC";
```

`$select_first` is the image they have selected to start from... Here is a basic example:

```
(1) a.jpg
(2) b.jpg
(3) c.jpg
(4) d.jpg
(5) e.jpg
```

If they don't select an image, it will start from `(1)` and continue through to `(5)` - that's fine.

If they select `(3)`, at the moment, the next image will be `(1)` and it will continue through to `(5)`, the next image SHOULD be `(4)` and continue to `(5)`...

Comment: Check this part `ORDER BY full_link = '$select_first'` don't use `=`. Just ORDER by full_link desc or ASC

Comment: Yes, but then when you click the image you want to view first, it won't show it, it will start from the beginning. That's why I am using `ORDER BY full_link = '$select_first'` as `$select_first` is their choice of the first image they want to start the order by.

Comment: It's trying to continue the results in order of results AFTER that '$select_first'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We does't use `=` in `ORDER BY full_link = '$select_first'`.  AS per your comment you can use `>` to get `full_link`  greater then value

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `new_images` WHERE `alb_ref` = '$alb_ref'
         AND  full_link >'$select_first'
         ORDER BY full_link ASC";
```

Comment: And here is me thinking you could only use those kind of operators for numbers. Thanks very much, defiantly pointed me in the right direction!